# Uploaded Application Still Didn't Show Up in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my application into Google Play Store 12 hours ago. Still, I cannot see my application, I also checked with package name like "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.package.name"

Is there any more search options?

I know this is a common problem and general answers are be patiance and refresh the page, but I also have another question.

Before releasing your app, as you know Play Store asks which countries do you want to publish. Is there any disadvantage for chosing all countries? I am started to think it is still not in store because I chose all countries.

12 hours passed, started to worry. My development page says it's released. So still waiting.

Comment: be patience.. wait for 24 hours atleast..

Comment: This link might give you some answers: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/189028?hl=en

Comment: Thanks man, but my app doesn't require any permissions, as the link says. It is very basic. I am also checking Play Store in my desktop.

Comment: Did you check the "Application Visibility and Discoverability" link too?

Comment: Yes. I am checking with publisher name also. And my manifest is default, just few activites, no permission.

Comment: Well then, as suggested by the user above, just wait for 12 hours more. I don't think there's a lot you can do right now anyway. All the best to you!

Comment: Thanks man, as you said nothing to do now. I will wait for 12 hours more.